# Facebook, Omegle, Major Chat Applications Title Change on New Message

Tags: javascript, html, title

My question is, how does Facebook, Omegle, and major chat applications code the title change  on new message system. I want to, on change of a div, to change the `<title>` tag to something else than it already is set as. This is most likely accomplished in Javascript, but I'm not an expert in Javascript, so how is this written?

Comment: how do they set the timeouts? so it says "New Message From" then something else then "New Message From" again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document.title).

Some part of the code is obviously modifying the `<div>`.  That's where you need to add the code to modify `document.title`.

Comment: I know about that, it doesn't tell me how to change the title on the change of a div. I also want to be able to detect whether they are actually on the page or not, to trigger that event accordingly.

Comment: Alright, so, how do we detect whether or not they are on the page?
EDIT: Would detecting and setting a variable based on if an element or not was focused work for this?